# "invalid operands to binary expression" at std::istringstream ">>" operator

Tags: c++, clion

I'm using Clion IDE and the editor is telling me there is an error at the first extraction operator `>>` here `memTotalStream >> _ >> total;` and I can't quite figure out the reason of error.

```
float LinuxParser::MemoryUtilization() {
    string avail, free, total;
    float used = 0.0;

    std::ifstream stream(kProcDirectory + kMeminfoFilename);

    if (stream.is_open()) {
        string _; // placeholder for unused string

        string MemTotalLine;
        std::getline(stream, MemTotalLine);
        std::istringstream memTotalStream(MemTotalLine);
        memTotalStream >> _ >> total;
    }

    return used;
}
```

[image: clion err]

Error txt:

```
***Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::istringstream' (aka ibasic_istringstream<char>') and istd::_1::string' (aka Ibasic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char»'))***
```

Comment: Copy and paste the error message _as text_.  That image is unsearchable and unreadable.

Comment: Do you have `#include <string>` in the file?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica yes, `#include <string>` and `using std::string;`

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm updating with image error text 

Comment: Do note that all of `string avail = 0, free = 0, total = 0;` is undefined behavior.  You are construing strings will a null pointer constant and `std::string`'s constructor explicitly forbids that.  Change the code to `string avail, free, total;`

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica thx - I updated it `string avail, free, total;` still same error, however.

Comment: The code should work.  Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: It compiles without errors, I'm just frustrated with the IDE's error here.

Comment: Some seaching around suggests two things: 1. Make sure you have the latest version of CLion, as this bug has apparently been plaguing this IDE for some time  (see [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-4681)) and 2. play with your toolchain versions, one of them may fix it

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-18265